# Extract an href from a specific div element

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract a specific link from a list. The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="icl-u-lg-hide">
    <a href="https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=60f4f1ed9ea60a29&amp;from=vj&amp;pos=bottom&amp;sjdu=YmZE5d5THV8u75cuc0H6Y26AwfY51UOGmh3Z9h4OvXiVStob9kU92ZXigtP-tVuXnUUKYs5yKqp3Fg7KgmoxhA&amp;astse=65cca94a29bb2a04&amp;assa=2009" referrerpolicy="origin" rel="noopener" target="_blank" role="link" class="icl-Button icl-Button--primary icl-Button--lg icl-Button--block">Apply Now</a>
</div>
```

I have accessed the div with the following code:

```
list = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'icl-u-lg-hide'})
```

This returns a list with all the elements in this div But I'm not sure how to access or return only the href. Is there somebody that could help me? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over the `list` and print the `href` attribute of the `a` tag within the `div`. And one important thing to note -- Don't use keywords such as `list` as variable names. Here is the code:

```
div_lst = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "icl-u-lg-hide")

for div in div_lst:
    try:
        print(div.a['href'])
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

Here is the full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="icl-u-lg-hide">
    <a href="https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=60f4f1ed9ea60a29&amp;from=vj&amp;pos=bottom&amp;sjdu=YmZE5d5THV8u75cuc0H6Y26AwfY51UOGmh3Z9h4OvXiVStob9kU92ZXigtP-tVuXnUUKYs5yKqp3Fg7KgmoxhA&amp;astse=65cca94a29bb2a04&amp;assa=2009" referrerpolicy="origin" rel="noopener" target="_blank" role="link" class="icl-Button icl-Button--primary icl-Button--lg icl-Button--block">Apply Now</a>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')
div_lst = soup.find_all('div', class_ = "icl-u-lg-hide")

for div in div_lst:
    try:
        print(div.a['href'])
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

Output:

```
https://www.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=60f4f1ed9ea60a29&from=vj&pos=bottom&sjdu=YmZE5d5THV8u75cuc0H6Y26AwfY51UOGmh3Z9h4OvXiVStob9kU92ZXigtP-tVuXnUUKYs5yKqp3Fg7KgmoxhA&astse=65cca94a29bb2a04&assa=2009
```

Comment: thanks! But this throws an TypeError:

 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: It would be better if you provide the html code as a text instead of an image as it would be easier for testing

Comment: @borisvanax I tried it out with the html u provided and my code worked fine. Check out my latest edit.

Comment: I'm not sure why but when I print all the ```div.a``` elements separately it prints one 1x href and 3x None. Which gives the TypeError. What I am trying to do is scrape the link of the 'Apply On Company Site' from this link: 
 https://www.indeed.com/viewjob?jk=60f4f1ed9ea60a29&from=serp&vjs=3

Comment: Check out my latest edit. Just use a ```try-except``` block to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sushil has pointed out, you can simply iterate over your list which contains all `href` attribute of the `a` tag using the `for loop`. Then point to the specific class you are interested in:

```py
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

for a in soup.find('a', {'class': 'icl-u-lg-hide'})['href']:
    print('Your url: ', a['href'])
```

This will print all the `href` of the class you are looking for.